# I can't access my sandbox - API only user activated by accident

Tags: api

"I was in my sandbox, and I was modifying a permission set when I accidentally enabled User Only API. Now I can't access my sandbox. How can I resolve this issue?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you're not modifying any other permissions. please log into [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) and select `Data >> Update`. then select `Permission set` and select `Single Record` and provide the 'ID' of the Permission set (which you're enabled the PermissionsApiUserOnly accidently or query the ID and provide here) and after overwrite the below row,

> PermissionsApiUserOnly into False

Then confirm the update and after try to login into Salesforce via normal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If they don't have the ID, they can also query for it.

Comment: How do I get the permission set ID?

Comment: Execute the soql `SELECT id, Name FROM Permissionset WHERE PermissionsApiUserOnly = TRUE` it's gives the list of permission set with ID including the permission set which you're accidentally enabled that API USER ONLY Permission.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. i'll be careful the next time

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to log in to your org through the API. You could write a script in [JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/) or even native JavaScript (NodeJS). Once you're in, you can use the relevant API calls to retrieve the permission set, remove the errant permission, and then deploy the changes back to Salesforce. If you're not a developer, you'll need to enlist the help of one. It may honestly be easier to just delete the sandbox and create a new one.